# Can I use object spread syntax in angular + ngrx?

Tags: javascript, object, redux, ngrx, spread-syntax

I was reading from [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) about the object spread syntax and I'm trying to use it in my project, my setup is the following:

- angular 2
- angular/cli 1.0.0-rc.0
- ngrx/core 1.2.0
- ngrx/store 2.2.1
- rxjs 5.1.0
- typescript 2.0.10

In my reducer.ts I have

```
export interface State {
  [id: number]: string
}

export function reducer(state= {}, action: Action): State {
case 'TEST':
  return {
    ...state,
    2: 'foo'
  }
}
```

But I got the following compiling error, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong:

```
Property assignment expected
Type '{ 2: string; state: State; }' is not assignable to type 'State'
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'State'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the version of TypeScript that you are using.

Support for the object properties spread syntax was [introduced in TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html):

> ### Object Spread and Rest
>
> TypeScript 2.1 brings support for [ES2017 Spread and Rest](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).
>
> Similar to array spread, spreading an object can be handy to get a shallow copy:
>
> ```
> let copy = { ...original };
> ```

Comment: great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Generally speaking can I update the typescript version to the latest one in an angular project? Or does a specific version of angular requires a specific version(s) of typescript ?

Comment: I don't recall any of the recent TypeScript versions being particularly problematic. I usually keep most things as up-to-date as possible, so it's been a while since I've used the version you mentioned in the question. There have been breaking changes, but they've been in my code.

Comment: There is a comprehensive document on versions, features and changes here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript